# Monte Carlo Simulation to Find Number of "Two-Pairs" (Python)

Tags: python

I am attempting to answer the following question:

For this exercise, you are to complete the function two_pair_prob, which estimates the probability of rolling two pairs with n independent dice rolls, over n trials. A "pair" is two dice with the same value, and "two pairs" is two distinct pairs of dice with the same value. For example, the following sequences contain two pairs over 5 rolls: (2, 1, 1, 3, 2), (3, 4, 3, 6, 4). Note that we are not interested in the probability of rolling exactly two pairs, but rather the probability of rolling two pairs or more. For example, the following also count as two pairs over 5 rolls: (1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1). The following do not count as two pairs over 5 rolls: (1, 1, 2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 6, 5, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

The solution I have built is as follows:

```
def roll_dice():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    if dice1==dice2:
        return True

def two_pair_prob(n_rolls, n_trials):
    twopairs = 0
    for x in range(1,n_trials+1):
        y = n_rolls
        count = 0
        while y > 0:
            if roll_dice():
                count+=1
            else:
                pass
            y-=1
        if count > 1:
            twopairs+=1
    return twopairs/n_trials
```

However, when I run a test for the code, it never finishes running and doesn't provide a result. I feel I may be misinterpreting the question and what a "two-pair" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works fine for me:

```
import random

def roll_dice(n):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]

def has_two_pairs_or_more(rolls):
    counts = {}
    for roll in rolls:
        counts[roll] = counts.get(roll, 0) + 1

    count_greater_than_1 = sum(count > 1 for count in counts.values())
    count_greater_than_3 = any(count > 3 for count in counts.values())

    return count_greater_than_1 >= 2 or count_greater_than_3

def two_pair_prob(n, m):
    two_pair_count = 0

    for _ in range(m):
        rolls = roll_dice(n)
        if has_two_pairs_or_more(rolls):
            two_pair_count += 1

    probability = two_pair_count / m
    return probability

n_rolls = 5
n_trials = 100000
result = two_pair_prob(n_rolls, n_trials)

print(f"The estimated probability of rolling two pairs or more over {n_rolls} rolls and {n_trials} trials is: {result}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Counter` to get the frequency of each roll, then sum the number of pairs.

```
def two_pair_prob(n_rolls, n_trials):
    from collections import Counter
    return sum(
        sum(v // 2 for v in Counter(
            random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n_rolls)).values()) > 1
        for _ in range(n_trials)
    ) / n_trials
```

Answer (score 1):

Several of the other answers provide working code that can figure out if you've rolled two pairs or not. But they tend to be highly specific to that question, rather than creating a general framework that could count three-pairs, or two three-of-a-kinds, or whatever other problem you might have. Here's code that can count arbitrary multiples, and then an application of it to the two-pairs problem (and some arbitrarily chosen others).

```
from collections import Counter
from random import randint

def count_n_of_a_kind(n, dice):
    count = Counter(dice)
    num_n_of_a_kind = sum(c // n for c in count.values())
    return num_n_of_a_kind

def at_least_x_n_of_a_kinds(x, n, dice):
    return count_n_of_a_kind(n, dice) >= x

def x_n_of_a_kind_prob(x, n, num_dice, num_trials):
    return sum(at_least_x_n_of_a_kinds(x, n, [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(num_dice)])
               for _ in range(num_trials)
           ) / num_trials

def two_pairs_prob(num_dice, num_trials):
    return x_n_of_a_kind_prob(2, 2, num_dice, num_trials)

def three_pairs_prob(num_dice, num_trials):
    return x_n_of_a_kind_prob(3, 2, num_dice, num_trials)

def two_three_of_a_kinds_prob(num_dice, num_trials):
    return x_n_of_a_kind_prob(2, 3, num_dice, num_trials)
```